# What is valid syntax for spark hive create table with USING and PARTITIONED BY clauses?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create hive table in orc format with following command passed to `SparkSesssion.sql(...)`:

```
CREATE TABLE `db`.`table`(
_id                     string,
...
)
PARTITIONED BY (load_date string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
USING ORC
```

And getting exception like `mismatched input 'USING' expecting <EOF>`
Changing places for above clauses don't help.

[Official documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable) omits this part or at least I'm unable to find it.

What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: There isn't USING. It is wrong.

Comment: @Lamanus is it Spark syntax ?

Comment: Yeap, it is hive query. Is there a spark syntax for sql? I don't think so.

Comment: `spark.sql('create table db.table(id, string) stored as orc')` will use all the above formats you specified.

Comment: @samkart well, I've tried that and it results in `The format of the existing table db.table is HiveFileFormat. It doesn't match the specified format OrcFileFormat` when executing `df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).format("orc").saveAsTable("db.table")`

Comment: They don't go hand in hand. You'll have to insert or create the sql way. Hive does not support what you're trying to do.

Comment: @samkart sorry, I didn't get that. I specified orc format in both places - during create table and during saveAsTable, for some reason that doesn't work

Comment: `df.registerTempTable('temptable')` then `spark.sql('create table db.table stored as orc as select * from temptable')` will do what you want

Comment: Spark or Hive does not support by default what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think this is what you're trying - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no USING tag in hive DDL statements:

You need to use stored as ORC or just the input and output format

```
CREATE TABLE `db`.`table`(
_id                     string,
...
)
PARTITIONED BY (load_date string)
STORED AS ORC
```

Comment: thank you, I've tried this and it result for me in exception message `The format of the existing table db.table is HiveFileFormat. It doesn't match the specified format OrcFileFormat` when executing `df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).format("orc").saveAsTable("db.table")`

Comment: If you are running saveAsTable then you should not have the table created before. If you already have a ORC table created then skip the saveAsTable and format part and just do a write.

Comment: you mean using `insertInto` ? as I see it ignores order of columns, so not applicable to my usecase

Comment: You could do insert into too, but you could pre-configure the order of the columns as per the destination table and then do the write. Some thing like : df.select("col1","col2").write.mode()